# basic java: scanning files, arrays

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Extremely new to programming. I have looked up a lot of similar programs but I get lost trying to relate them to this program. Just looking for a simple push in the right direction

Scanners are handy for reading input that is stored in a file. For this exercise, create a file called "c:\aaa\numbers.txt" that contains the following data:

```
  1.2   2.3  3.4  4.5
  2.0   3.0  4.0  5.0
  6.0   7.0  8.0  9.0
```

Read each line, convert the numbers in each line to doubles, and print each row of numbers and their total.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;

public class ScanningFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner numbersFile = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));

        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

        while (numbersFile.hasNextLine()) {
            tokens = numbersFile.nextline();
            // put each value into an array with String#split();
            String[] numStrings = line.split(" ");
            // parse number string into doubles
            double[] numbs = new double[numString.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                nums[i] = Double.parseDouble(numStrings[i]);
            }

        }
        numbersFile.close();

        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

That is what I have tried so far, but to be honest that is way over my head. I'm getting very lost

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: And you are stuck with what? Did you search how to read a line from a file?

Comment: Okk sir.Anything more you want  ??

Comment: Shoe some code please

Comment: SO surely needs a "Do your homework yourself"-button...

Comment: From your code excerpt, it looks like you're getting the numbers successfully, and all you need to do is add them up.  Is that right?  If that's the case, you'll need an extra variable representing the total on each line, and as you loop through the numbers, add each one that you encounter to the total.

Answer (score 2):

A gentle push:

1. Use scanner to read it all as one block
2. Look into the `String.split()` method to break them up
3. Look into `Double.parseDouble()` to convert them
4. Add them together and print the results

Comment: why not just use the `Scanner`'s `nextDouble` method inside of a `while(myScanner.hasNextDouble())` to get each double instead of having to mess with Strings?

Comment: @JonnyHenly because if you do that, you don't know where each line ends.

Comment: @DavidWallace oh ok, I see what your saying.